# photo filters in iOS

Tags: ios, filter, photo

I have a question about applying photo filters in iOS. The filter itself will not be added/adjusted by the user manually, but rather automatically applied to the photo once they categorize and upload their photo to a table view. Simply put, all photos tagged by users in category "x" will be blue in a table UI, all photos in category "B" will be yellow in table UI etc...The photos will be displayed in a view format much like VEVO (if your familiar)...

I am assuming the best way to do this would just to create a class for each category based filter?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Core Image framework, it contains specific methods to apply filters.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/coreimagefilterreference/index.html